# My world keeps not responding correctly, how do i fix that?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was using a lan server on my favorite world and when i saved and exited the world everything worked fine. Then later i tried to enter the world and it glitched out a bit at the load screen and when i got onto the world, it was VERY unresponsive, by that I mean that i would break a block and nothing would happen, the block just disappears, when i try to access chests it takes a good two minutes to see the contents. After a little while it crashes and i get this error code:

```
  Minecraft has crashed!      
  ----------------------      

Minecraft has stopped running because it encountered a problem; Exception in server tick loop

A full error report has been saved to C:\Users\SovietOnion\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\crash-reports\crash-2012-11-15_00.11.55-server.txt - Please include a copy of that file (Not this screen!) if you report this crash to anyone; without it, they will not be able to help fix the crash :(



--- BEGIN ERROR REPORT 1e5074f8 --------
Full report at:
C:\Users\SovietOnion\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\crash-reports\crash-2012-11-  15_00.11.55-server.txt
Please show that file to Mojang, NOT just this screen!

Generated 11/15/12 12:12 AM

-- System Details --
Details:
Minecraft Version: 1.4.4
Operating System: Windows 7 (amd64) version 6.1
Java Version: 1.7.0_05, Oracle Corporation
Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
Memory: 318267992 bytes (303 MB) / 534249472 bytes (509 MB) up to 954466304 bytes (910 MB)
JVM Flags: 2 total; -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
AABB Pool Size: 23258 (1302448 bytes; 1 MB) allocated, 23258 (1302448 bytes; 1 MB) used
Suspicious classes: No suspicious classes found.
IntCache: cache: 15, tcache: 0, allocated: 3, tallocated: 63
Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
Vec3 Pool Size: 149614 (8378384 bytes; 7 MB) allocated, 149614 (8378384 bytes; 7 MB) used
Player Count: 0 / 8; []
Type: Integrated Server (map_client.txt)
Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and both client + server brands are untouched.

java.lang.NullPointerException
at cf.b(SourceFile:103)
at cf.a(SourceFile:35)
at iv.b(SourceFile:437)
at gm.a(SourceFile:72)
at bdr.b(SourceFile:73)
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.r(SourceFile:769)
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.q(SourceFile:686)
at bdo.q(SourceFile:117)
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(SourceFile:620)
at fy.run(SourceFile:856)
--- END ERROR REPORT 8eb5620c ----------
```

When it says that the full error report is located at "" It says this:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// I'm sorry, Dave.

Time: 11/15/12 12:18 AM
Description: Exception in server tick loop

java.lang.NullPointerException
at cf.b(SourceFile:103)
at cf.a(SourceFile:35)
at iv.b(SourceFile:437)
at gm.a(SourceFile:72)
at bdr.b(SourceFile:73)
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.r(SourceFile:769)
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.q(SourceFile:686)
at bdo.q(SourceFile:117)
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(SourceFile:620)
at fy.run(SourceFile:856)


-- System Details --
Details:
Minecraft Version: 1.4.4
Operating System: Windows 7 (amd64) version 6.1
Java Version: 1.7.0_05, Oracle Corporation
Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
Memory: 190459000 bytes (181 MB) / 536018944 bytes (511 MB) up to 954466304 bytes (910 MB)
JVM Flags: 2 total; -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
AABB Pool Size: 23208 (1299648 bytes; 1 MB) allocated, 23208 (1299648 bytes; 1 MB) used
Suspicious classes: No suspicious classes found.
IntCache: cache: 15, tcache: 0, allocated: 3, tallocated: 63
Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
Vec3 Pool Size: 149633 (8379448 bytes; 7 MB) allocated, 149633 (8379448 bytes; 7 MB) used
Player Count: 0 / 8; []
Type: Integrated Server (map_client.txt)
Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and both client + server brands are untouched.
```

Comment: You said it's on a LAN: are you sure no-one else has accessed it (and perhaps left behind a lag-bomb of some kind)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had any previous mods installed, re-install them. It seems as though you overflowed the world with mods and it became dependent on them and after you updated or cleaned your .minecraft or whatever of the sort it corrupted the world.

Answer (score 6):

> "Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and both client + server brands are untouched."

Minecraft sometimes crashes if it is modded. I have had this problem many times. If you force update, this will re-download Minecraft and keep the worlds in the saves folder.

**REMEMBER: Back up your .minecraft folder before doing anything that may mess with the configuration that you already have**

Comment: Ya, I never had a mod installed on that .minecraft file, other worlds worked perfectly fine...

Answer (score 1):

If you download a mod, try deleting the meta-inf folder in bin folder / minecraft.jar folder. Then try to login. If it doesn't work, try again.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, so I swept my `.minecraft` folder (except the saves) and it worked absolutely fine! No more crashes or anything and my mods all still working!

Comment: The problem was solved already, sorry mate